# Design library and support library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I want to use '**com.android.support:design:22.2.0**' in my Android Studio(1.3) project but when i add 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0' to dependencies{} i get 103 errors and i can not get rid of this errors.

Same happens if i try to use a new version of appcompat. Now i have 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+' in my build.gradle.

Anyone have any idea?

My errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:generateDebugSources, :generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72211Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2220Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices6111Library UP-TO-DATE
:preparePaketekBeaconEstimoteSdkUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources
:processDebugManifest
:processDebugResources
/Users/matejl/Documents/AndroidStudio Projects/Paketek-beacon/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services/6.1.11/res/values/wallet_colors.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "color" has already been defined
/Users/matejl/Documents/AndroidStudio Projects/Paketek-beacon/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/res/values-v21/values-v21.xml
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(120, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(121, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(118, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(119, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(120, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(121, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(118, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(119, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(213, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(213, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(120, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(121, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(118, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(119, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(120, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(121, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(118, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(119, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/matejl/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.222 secs
Information:103 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

and my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
 //   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile project(':estimote-sdk')
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        releaseconfig {
            keyAlias 'mobile'
            keyPassword '85922881'
            storeFile file('/Users/matejl/Documents/AndroidStudio Projects/MobileWorker-SZ/release-mobileworker.jks')
            storePassword '85922881'
            //master passsowr 85922881
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19

    }
productFlavors {
}
}
```

THANKS :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using support and design v22 you have to compile against SDK 22 so you have to modify your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`:

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
```

Remember download the API SDK 22 with the SDK Manager.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Almost all erros gone. There is 1 more. 
    /Users/matejl/Documents/AndroidStudio Projects/Paketek-beacon/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-wallet/7.5.0/res/values/wallet_colors.xml
Error:(2) Attribute "color" has already been defined.     



I also changed the play service to latest

Comment: Try with the last version of Play Services `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`

Comment: i comment all the dependencies and i get error :Error:(2) Attribute "color" has already been defined but for my color.xml file in /res/values/... i dont have any idea. on another stackoverflow post i read that play-service already have appcompat-v7 build inside so i dont have to compile it separately.

Comment: Do you have any attribute `color` defined in a custom `attrs` xml file?

Comment: No. I named colors for their purpose. like blue_background.

Comment: I don't know if you did it but you also need change `appcompat` to `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'`. You have to keep all "Android" dependencies in same version

Answer (score 0):

@Arturo

I had a same problem with "title" not "color".
You said

> "Do you have any attribute color defined in a custom attrs xml files?"

Yes I did, I define "title" in my attrs.xml.

I changed it by "edittext_title", so I worked!

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question but a mere comment directed at the poster of an other answer.